# Как отправить XML и получить ответ с помощью Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

Не могу отправить и получить ответ с помощью Guzzle. Есть XML с переменными
URL адрес сервера получателя, XML код xml

```
$url = 'https://example.com';
$xml = '<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
                <message>
                    <method name="getPlayerInfo">
                      <credentials login=".$test." password=".$ptest." />
                    </method>
                </message>';
```

Comment: для начала опубликуйте синтаксически корректный php код.

Comment: ну дак и отправляете то вы его каким образом?

Comment: Я пока не отправляю)))), домен example.com немогу разобратся с Guzzle

Comment: дак откройте документацию, там вроде вполне доступно все с примерами изложено. guzzle в целом и не нужна, запросы отправлять можно и более стандартными средствами

Comment: Спасибо, делаю!